# need help for matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink

This figure illustrates my problem:

[image]

**t** (in the **X1** calculation) value changes from **0** to **e*tz***. If its value reaches **etz** it has to start from **0** again and again.
This situation has to continue during simulation (I need a loop!). However, **t** is simulation time and I cannot force it to be zero. So maybe I need a parallel time to the simulation time but I don't how to create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use modulo operator.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html

For example:

```
X1 = abs((mod(t,e*tz)-e*tz/2)/(1.125*c*tz))
```

This part:

```
mod(t,e*tz)
```

Will be >= 0 and < e*tz and will repeat the way you want.

In the future, please provide a better title for your question.  Also, providing a screen shot of your code is not the preferred way to include code.

Comment: thnx for your interest but modulo is not convenient for this calculation. becasue you know The “mod” function directly computes the remainder of a division operation.I'm not looking for a remainder. I just look for a function which can make **t** valeu to **0** when **t** reach **e*tz** valeu.

Comment: @prot Applying `mod` wraps the values of `t` so that they are less than `e*tz`. This is exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: @Eitan T **t** values start from **0** and continue untill value reach **e*tz**. Consider this as a period and this period have to start from **0** again till values be equel to the **e*tz**. As far as I know **mod** computes the remainder of a division operation. For example mod(21,4) gives **1** (calculation is 21/4 = 4*5+ **1** )

Comment: @prot Exactly. Suppose that `e*tz` is 5, and `t` changes from 0 to 20. So `mod(t, e*tz)` gives the following 20 values: `0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4....`. A modulus of an arithmetic series produces a periodic series.

Comment: @Eitan T many thx for your interest. ok maybe you are right. I should check it and then inform you again..

Comment: **@corbin** ,**@Eitan T**    Thank you so much guys, you were right and it worked as I wished...Thank you so much again.. you are my heros:)

Comment: @prot I was offline.  Thanks to Eitan for explaining why it was correct.